# AngularJS $injector: unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have  a problem I  have this piece of code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl" ng-app="tradePlace">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="./helpers/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="./helpers/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="./helpers/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/routes/routes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/services/loginService.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/controllers/indexCntrl.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-view></body>
</html>
```

Routes.js:

```
var app = angular.module('tradePlace', ['ngRoute', 'tradeCntrls']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($route, $location) {
    $route.
    when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/index'
    }).
    when('/index', {
        templateUrl: './includes/templates/index.html',
        controller: 'indexCntrl'
    }).
    when('/register', {
        templateUrl: './includes/templates/register.php',
        controller: 'indexCntrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index'
    });

    $location.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

indexCtrnl.js:

```
var app = angular.module('tradeCntrls', []);

app.controller('indexCntrl', ['$scope' , 'loginService', function($scope, login){
    $scope.login = function() {

    }
}])
```

loginService.js

```
app.factory('loginService', ['', function(){
    return function login(){

    };
}])
```

So, I get this error:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

The error page on the AngularJS docs says:

> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a
>   required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined
>   and spelled correctly

Well, I`m sure is spelled correctly and it should be defined. I have already tried to put a getter in the loginServices.js to get the tradePlace module and also tried to use a getter with the tradePlaceCntrls module but I still get the error.

I don`t know how to fix this.

Comment: I'm guessing it is because you're trying to inject a `''` service into your `loginService`. It should be `app.factory('loginService', [function(){` I think.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint on the line which gives you the Error, from there you should be able to read what is going on inside the Error Object data. 
Usually i get this error when i've used a Module that i haven't added inside the app require.

Comment: Thanks it worked, also thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is it but have you tried defining your factory like this?

```
app.factory('loginService', function(){
    return function login(){

    };
});
```

You don't need the array as your login service doesn't have any dependencies. That `''` might be causing your issue. Try removing the array as it is not necessary in this case.

Also, you could define your login service as a service:

```
app.service('loginService', function(){
    return function login(){

    };
});
```